# MongoDB aggregate query $match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I create a query that returns the farmland details and all events that is connected with it (see below)
Now I want to filter and return only events that have the `status` field not equal to `delete`. I tried with $match operator but it doesn't work... Is there someone who can help me with?
Here are the collections of the database:
**Farmland collections**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5909d9bc19383e2a16378271"),
    "SUID" : "IT0001",
    "id" : "A",
    "UUID" : "CAL123",
    "name" : "Pratosaiano (Maza)",
    "status" : "close"
}
```

**Events collections**

```
...
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5909e3387786e52c90f158da"),
    "SUID" : "IT0001",
    "farmland" : "B",
    "opening" : "00:00",
    "closing" : "00:00",
    "type" : "scheduled",
    "days" : [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "active" : true,
    "status" : "add",
    "id" : 204
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590b4ec6cdddea05130fbc3b"),
    "SUID" : "IT0001",
    "farmland" : "B",
    "opening" : "00:00",
    "closing" : "01:00",
    "type" : "semiautomatic",
    "active" : true,
    "status" : "add",
    "id" : 16
}
...
```

**The query:**

```
db.farmlands.aggregate([
{
    $match: {  
        "SUID": "IT0001",
        "id": "B",
    }
}, 
{  
    $lookup: { 
        localField: "id", 
        from: "events", 
        foreignField: "farmland", 
        as: "events" 
    }  
},  
{  
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,  
        "SUID": 1,  
        "id": 1,  
        "name": 1, 
        "events.id": 1,  
        "events.type": 1,  
        "events.opening": 1,
        "events.closing": 1, 
        "events.days": 1, 
        "events.active": 1, 
        "events.status": 1 
    }
}]);
```

**The output of this query**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5909d9bc19383e2a16378272"),
    "SUID" : "IT0001",
    "id" : "B",
    "UUID" : "CAL123",
    "name" : "Pratosaiano (Maza)",
    "status" : "close",
    "events" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5909da8312452a289bbb62c1"),
            "SUID" : "IT0001",
            "farmland" : "B",
            "opening" : "07:00",
            "closing" : "08:00",
            "type" : "scheduled",
            "days" : [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "active" : true,
            "status" : "update",
            "id" : 237
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: I should add the `$match` operator for filter events status to the query but I don't know how to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: You will need to add `$project` stage with `$filter` after  `$lookup` to keep the non deleted events. Something like `{  
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,  
        "SUID": 1,  
        "id": 1,  
        "name": 1,
        "events": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$events",
                as: "result",
                cond: {
                    $ne: ["$$result.status", "delete"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},`

Comment: And where should I add the stage for removing the _id field in every event?

Comment: This will help. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-from-output-documents